# Writing an matrix alogrithm with multiple rules in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, operators

I'm trying to write an alogrithm in PHP for this matrix:
[image]

- 'risk profile' is from 1 to 5.
- 'compliance score' is from 0 to 5.
- The scores are then plotted in the matrix and given a frequency result
  (in months).
- The frequency results need to be colour coded in a RAG
  system on a sliding scale, high/red to low/green.
- Each frequency then needs to given a corresponding label e.g. HIGH/POOR

Is there a simple/elegant approach you could reccomend?

The frequency scores don't seem to be in a logical calculation.

I started with this approach...

```
//2months
if($riskScore == 1 && $complianceScore == 0 || $riskScore == 2 && $complianceScore == 0 || $riskScore == 1 && $complianceScore == 1)
{
    $totalRiskBg = "text-bg-danger";
    $label= "VERY HIGH / POOR";
    $frequency = "2 months";   
}  
//4 months
...
//6months
...
```

And so on but realised the labels can't all be grouped under one rule.

Comment: Are you looking for help generating that table or just generating the color codes for each value?

Comment: Not looking to generate the table, just need to calculate the respective score/s...

Comment: Without doing a bunch of  evaluation on the dataset, my first instinct would be to assign  "calculation scores" to each value. So 1-5 on the x-axis might be 1,2,4,8,16; and then 1-5 on the y axis might be 32,64,128,256,512. Then you can use bitwise arithmetic to quickly calculate a unique score which you can design rules around.

Comment: The image shows a table with 2 dimensions, so that would translate as an array with 2 dimensions, but I'm not sure to understand the expected result. How do you map frequency with the data in the image? Please describe what are the input data and what is the expected output: an image? an HTML table? a PHP array?

Comment: @A.L Yeah, I was thinking about using a muti-demisional array to assign the score values, RAG colours and values, but am not sure how they could be used to calculate the frequencies?
example: https://www.yahoobaba.net/php/php-multidimensional-associative-array

Comment: Do you want to calculate the frequencies? Aren't they constant numbers? Or do you want to reverse engineer the formula?

Comment: @A.L yeah but the calculation needs to be something like risk score x compliance score = frequency.

Comment: Since you already have the results, I don't see the need to calculate. Once data is put in an array like `$data = [0 => [1 => 2, 2 => 2], 1 => [1 => 2, 2 => 4]];`, you can get the frequency but searching the values in the array: `$data[$compliance][$risk]`. See [this code](https://3v4l.org/PfVDm).

Comment: So the $data variable = the frequency value? 
And I would just assign the RAG colour values in the array?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want is to find the colour over a 2 dimensional space? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation you can get the labels trivially by using a 2D array and rounding the indices.

Comment: 1. There's not much logic to how the values in that table progress. 2. There's not much likelihood that any of those values will change. 3. Even if they _do_ change, it is doubtful that they will follow any particular logic either. Answer: Just hardcode the numerical values in an array or config file and key the color codes to them.

Comment: Maybe I haven’t explained this well but the part I’m stumped on will be something like: if $risk = 1 && $compliance =0 $frequency = 2 months $colour = red $label=high/poor

Comment: What is the end result? Why not hardcode the values and colors in the HTML table? Using PHP to generate a static table is counter-productive here IMHO.

Comment: @A.L possibly, but I want to avoid displaying the entire table when all I need is the score. Point here, is to calculate the score rather looking it up in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The frequencies are static values, there's no need to calculate them.

We can store them in an array then retrieve the value we want by using the indexes:

```
// you'll have to add more data to cover all the cases
$data = [
    0 => [1 => 2, 2 => 2, 3 => 4, 4 => 4, 5 => 6],
    1 => [1 => 2, 2 => 4, 3 => 6, 4 => 6, 5 => 12],
];

$compliance = 0;
$risk = 2;
// retrieve the value
$frequency = $data[$compliance][$risk];

printf(
    'compliance %d and risk %d = %d months',
    $compliance, $risk, $frequency
);

print PHP_EOL;

$compliance = 1;
$risk = 5;
$frequency = $data[$compliance][$risk];

printf(
    'compliance %d and risk %d = %d months',
    $compliance, $risk, $frequency
);
```

Output:

```
compliance 0 and risk 2 = 2 months
compliance 1 and risk 5 = 12 months
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/MPJtI)

For the color, it depends on the number of months, so you can store the color for each of the different values (2, 4, 6 … months), then retrieve it from the number of months.